# JVisualVM -Xverify:none does not solve Redefinition failed with error 62

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile a simple java application using jvisualvm on Windows 7 64 bit. I am using Java 8 with JDK 1.8.0_131. I am able to see my application and use the Sample tab of VisualVM, however when I use the CPU option of the Profile tab I get a "Redefinition failed with error 62". This error is documented online and the common solution is to include the flag -Xverify:none when launching the application. However, using this flag has no effect for me. I have tried it with both the JVisualVM itself and my simple program jar neither makes a difference. Below are the terminal commands I am using.

Using Xverify with the simple program.

```
java -jar SimpleProfile.jar -Xverify:none
```

Using Xverify with jvisualvm

`./jvisualvm.exe -J-Xverify:none`

Both were run from a Git Bash terminal with not effect. I have tried comparable commands in CMD as well.

I do not have admin privileges on my PC and I noticed that I cannot use the Windows resource monitor. Is this possibly related to the issue or is there something wrong with my arguments?

Extra info:
When the profiler fails I get the following error in terminal

```
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol
version: 15)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session
Profiler Agent Error: Redefinition failed for classes:
sun.nio.fs.NativeBuffer$Deallocator
sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl$1
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop
sun.rmi.transport.DGCAckHandler$1
com.profiletest.Main
sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$Unmapper
java.io.DeleteOnExitHook$1
java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

$ScheduledFutureTask
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler
java.lang.ClassLoader
java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout
java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread
java.lang.reflect.Method
Profiler Agent Error: with message: Redefinition failed with

error 62
Check JVMTI documentation for this error code.
Debug: writing class file: sun.nio.fs.NativeBuffer

$Deallocator, into file: sun.nio.fs.NativeBuffer

$Deallocator.class
Debug: writing class file: sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl$1, into

file: sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl$1.class
Debug: writing class file:

sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop, into file:

sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.class
Debug: writing class file: sun.rmi.transport.DGCAckHandler$1,

into file: sun.rmi.transport.DGCAckHandler$1.class
Debug: writing class file: com.profiletest.Main, into file:

com.profiletest.Main.class
Debug: writing class file: sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

$Unmapper, into file: sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

$Unmapper.class
Debug: writing class file: java.io.DeleteOnExitHook$1, into

file: java.io.DeleteOnExitHook$1.class
Debug: writing class file: java.util.ResourceBundle

$RBClassLoader, into file: java.util.ResourceBundle

$RBClassLoader.class
Debug: writing class file:

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker, into file:

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.class
Debug: writing class file:

java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

$ScheduledFutureTask, into file:

java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

$ScheduledFutureTask.class
Debug: writing class file: java.lang.ref.Reference

$ReferenceHandler, into file: java.lang.ref.Reference

$ReferenceHandler.class
Debug: writing class file: java.lang.ClassLoader, into file:

java.lang.ClassLoader.class
Debug: writing class file: java.util.logging.LogManager

$Cleaner, into file: java.util.logging.LogManager

$Cleaner.class
Debug: writing class file:

com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout,

into file:

com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin

$Timeout.class
Debug: writing class file:

java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1, into file:

java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.class
Debug: writing class file:

sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler, into

file: sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport

$ConnectionHandler.class
Debug: writing class file: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask,

into file: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.class
Debug: writing class file: java.lang.ref.Finalizer

$FinalizerThread, into file: java.lang.ref.Finalizer

$FinalizerThread.class
Debug: writing class file: java.lang.reflect.Method, into

file: java.lang.reflect.Method.class
```

Answer (score 5):

java -Xverify:none -jar SimpleProfile.jar works. I guess I hadn't exhausted all the options.

Comment: Now that you say that, it makes perfectly sense. Everything after the `-jar jarfile` option is passed as arguments to your Java application, so JVM options have to be placed before that…

Comment: Yeah I feel kinda foolish, but at least now others can see this for a faster solution.

Comment: How can I use the noverify when trying to profile unit tests ?